# how can i retrieve the name of iis server where azure websites are deployed

Tags: iis, azure, scom

Can i connect remotely to azure IIS server where all the azure websites are deployed and monitor all those web applications using system center operations manager 2012 r2.Is it possible to get the name or ip address of the iis server under a azure subscription.
Thanks In Advance
Suresh Gaddam

Comment: Do you meed Azure Websites or website deployed as Cloud Service?

Comment: I mean i want to manage  n monitor my websites hosted on azure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about Azure Website, you can't RDP into the box.  The IIS server that serves those websites has about a million websites running off of it.  You might be able to get an IP address by pinging the Site URL listed on the website's dashboard but monitoring it with tools, doubt those hooks are open.

Comment: thanks it doesn't help me out,the website is not even giving the response when i ping it from my localmachine

Comment: I can ping my azure website, although it doesn't give me the ping return, it does tell me the IP address of the server.  Or if you are using ASP.Net you can follow the code in the link and get the IP Address...

Comment: http://wec-library.blogspot.com/2008/03/gets-ip-address-of-server-pc-using-c.html

Comment: i mean i got the ip address but it is not responding to the ping command it is like request time out